# Download you tube video using c#?

Tags: c#, youtube

I am trying to download you tube video using c# code but i am not getting proper code. I have searched many link but din't get any proper links and code.

I want to download the you tube video in my local folder with c# code. I have tried one link but that code just getting null video in my local folder so any one have the idea how can do that.

Below is the code i have tried so far.

```
var VedioUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + objYouTube.VideoID + ".mp4";

WebRequest MyRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(VedioUrl);
WebResponse MyResponse = MyRequest.GetResponse();
string RealURL = MyResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RealURL);
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, encode);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/youtube/" + objYouTube.VideoID + ".mp4"), true);
writer.Write(readStream.ReadToEnd());
writer.Close();
```

so here is my video url which i am trying to download : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/UCsiNPbLbwZk43FOCRrdKBlA.mp4"

Comment: [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) is a nice open source solution. You could add it in your app.

Comment: @AchaBill but how can used it any idea please give me some hint for that please.

Comment: Check out [Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AchaBill i am pass this beloe url in the question it's correct or not?and you have to code like this with your idea so please give me the new answer in this post please.

Comment: guys any one have the idea then pleas let me know i am facing the problem with few days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have find the solution for download you tube videos using c# code.

First need install the "**libvideo**" on **NuGet** package manager console in visual studio.

Here Fire this command on package manger console :

```
Install-Package VideoLibrary
```

First add this namespace on top in your controller :

```
using VideoLibrary;
```

Now here just write just code and pass the url link :

```
var VedioUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + objYouTube.VideoID + ".mp4";
var youTube = YouTube.Default;
var video = youTube.GetVideo(VedioUrl);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/youtube/" + video.FullName + ".mp4"), video.GetBytes());
```

Comment: This seems to leave out the audio.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed [youtube-dl](http://youtube-dl.org/) in your app.
It provides extensive Youtube download options.

Basically, you do something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"yourpath\youtube-dl.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFqrp4KSxio";
                myProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this [C# wapper for youtube-dl](https://github.com/detaybey/WrapYoutubeDl/blob/master/WrapYoutubeDl/AudioDownloader.cs).
You can extend it to suite your needs.

[Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so i need to youtube-dl refrence add in our .net c# solution right?

Comment: You need the binaries. i.e the executable.
You can use this [C# wrapper](https://github.com/detaybey/WrapYoutubeDl).

Comment: ok i will try and go with your solution then any problem face you can please help i have just give you one ping ok

Answer (score 0):

after install the **"libvideo"** on **NuGet** package manager console in visual studio.

and download **ffmpeg** for merge audio and video for best output .

follow this code :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using VideoLibrary;

namespace you_tube_download
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
            Console.WriteLine("write url video : ");
            string url = Console.ReadLine();
            string information = "";
            var videos = YouTube.Default.GetAllVideos(url);
            int hightaudio = 1;
            int hightvideo = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("\nlist all format \n");
            foreach (var item in videos)//write all file on this url
             {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Resolution+","+item.Format + "," + item.AudioFormat + "," + item.AudioBitrate + "," + item.ContentLength + "," + item.AdaptiveKind);
                if (item.AdaptiveKind.ToString() == "Audio" && item.AudioBitrate > hightaudio)
                {
                    hightaudio = item.AudioBitrate;
                    information = item.AudioFormat + "," + item.AudioBitrate+","+item.ContentLength;
                }
                if (item.Resolution > hightvideo)
                {
                    hightvideo = item.Resolution;
                }
            }
             Console.WriteLine("\ndownload high video resolotion {0} and high audio bitrate {1}",hightvideo,hightaudio);
             string[] split = information.Split(',');
            foreach (var item in videos)//download audio
            {
                if (split[0]== item.AudioFormat.ToString() && split[1] == item.AudioBitrate.ToString() && split[2] == item.ContentLength.ToString())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\ndownload audio with bitrate {0} and size {1}MB",item.AudioBitrate, Math.Round((double)item.ContentLength / 1000000, 2));
                    downloadbest(item, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file123456798.mp3");
                    Console.Write("end\n");
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in videos)//download video
            {
                if (item.Resolution==hightvideo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\ndownload video with Resolution {0} and size {1}MB", item.Resolution, Math.Round((double)item.ContentLength/1000000,2));
                    downloadbest(item, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file123456798.mp4");
                    Console.Write("end\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("wait for marge");
            combine();
            File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file123456798.mp3");
            File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file123456798.mp4");
            Console.WriteLine("press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n" + ex);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        }
        static void combine()
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file123456798.mp4\" -i \"" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file123456798.mp3\" -preset veryfast  \"" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\final.mp4\"";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        static void downloadbest(YouTubeVideo y, string patch)
        {
            int total = 0;
            FileStream fs =null;
            Stream streamweb = null;
            WebResponse w_response = null;
            try
            {
                WebRequest w_request = WebRequest.Create(y.Uri);
                if (w_request != null)
                {
                    w_response = w_request.GetResponse();
                    if (w_response != null)
                    {
                        fs = new FileStream(patch, FileMode.Create);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[128*1024];
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        streamweb = w_response.GetResponseStream();
                        Console.WriteLine("Download Started");
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = streamweb.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            total += bytesRead;
                            Console.Write($"\rDownloading ({Math.Round(((double)total/(int)y.ContentLength) * 100, 2)}%) {total}/{y.ContentLength}     ");
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nDownload Complete");
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n" + ex);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (w_response != null) w_response.Close();
                if (fs != null) fs.Close();
                if (streamweb != null) streamweb.Close();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: At this line WebRequest w_request = WebRequest.Create(y.Uri); an error thrown, System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'                 Symbol loading for optimized module Jurassic.dll was skipped because Just My Code is enabled